# how to interpret the accuracy of a model output using caret package

Tags: r

I am using caret package to train a model and would like to get the accuracy of the model. A common way I heard is to use confusionMatrix. However, when I run my code below, the trained model gives me some accuracy values that are slightly different from what confusionMatrix() reports. So my question is what accuracy should I use? How to interpret the accuracy the model gives directly in the console?

```
ModelRF_ALL_b <- train(price~.,method="rf",data=datatraining_b)
ModelRF_ALL_b
```

The console reports the following

```
Random Forest 

8143 samples
   8 predictor
   2 classes: '0', '1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 
Summary of sample sizes: 8143, 8143, 8143, 8143, 8143, 8143, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  Accuracy   Kappa    
  2     0.9948108  0.9843501
  4     0.9945824  0.9836512
  7     0.9940732  0.9821099

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 2.
```

I can also run confusionMatrix()

```
confusionMatrix(datatraining_b$price,
predict(ModelRF_ALL_b,datatraining_b))
```

It gives accuracy of 1.

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

      Reference
Prediction    0    1
     0 6414    0
     1    0 1729

           Accuracy : 1          
             95% CI : (0.9995, 1)
No Information Rate : 0.7877     
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16  

              Kappa : 1          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA         

        Sensitivity : 1.0000     
        Specificity : 1.0000     
     Pos Pred Value : 1.0000     
     Neg Pred Value : 1.0000     
         Prevalence : 0.7877     
     Detection Rate : 0.7877     
   Detection Prevalence : 0.7877     
  Balanced Accuracy : 1.0000     

   'Positive' Class : 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interpret these values as **in-sample** accuracies with and without resampling, respectively.

The package `caret` performs bootstrapped resampling with 25 repetition when you fit the model, which can be seen in your model output. So, the accuracy value is based on 25 x 8143 observations. In order to create the confusion matrix, you are using the final model (the one with mtry = 2) to predict the outcomes from the training sample, which has a length of 8143. Therefore, it is normal to have a slight difference in corresponding accuracies.

You need to be careful while assessing the goodness-of-fit because you are training and evaluating your model using the same dataset. No surprise that you get a large accuracy. It is always good to evaluate your final model with an unseen dataset to ensure its performance and detect possible over-fitting issues.